# How to fix FTP to self?

Tags: ftp

I am able to `ftp` into my server, but when log on via ssh and do `ftp localhost`, I receive the message `ftp> ftp: connect: Connection refused`. I think I need it to ftp to itself for wordpress. Is this a firewall issue? How can I diagnose it?

Comment: forgive me, but why do you need to FTP to yourself? Is your FTP service running (let us know your O.S to help more).

Comment: @n34_panda Using Ubuntu 12.10. I have LAMP installed on there, but I'm using the default `ftp`.

Comment: This question does not pertain to `vsftpd`. I wound up fixing it by installing `vsftpd` and following the documentation on it, but I couldn't find any documentation on the default `ftp` program.

Answer (score 1):

In general you'll probably need to tell your ftpd to listen to all interfaces.

Share with us your flavor of ftp daemon and its current configuration.

Comment: I was using the one that ships with Ubuntu 12.10 or `LAMP`. I'm not sure which that is. I was looking for the config file, but I can't seem to find it, or the address to it online.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, here is a possibility, I am basing this on a comparison of my ubuntu 12.04 Server - i am using the default vsftpd - If I was to guess I would imagine the configuraiton is fine but you haven't started the FTP Service:

Restart your vsFTPd server :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

To Stop/Start/Restart vsftpd service you can use:

```
sudo service vsftpd stop/start/restart
```

One more thing to check, the vsftpd configuration file, back it up first:

```
cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.old
```

usevi with vim/gedit or whatever to make a small amendment

```
sudo vi /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Look for "local_enable" set it to YES if it is set to NO, otherwise add it to the end of the file. It should look like :

```
local_enable=YES
```

Comment: Ok. this is good for `vsftpd`, but I was looking for help with the one that Ubuntu ships with, which I don't know where the `conf` file was. I wound up just installing `vsftpd` and following the ubuntu documentation on it, which this looks like, but I was hoping to get some answers that I couldn't find from the web. Thank you anyway, for your help.

Comment: I am using ubuntun12.04 and it ships with vsftpd, the config file was at /etc/vsftd but I get your meaning.

Comment: According to the documentation for `12.04` and `12.10`, `vsftpd` has to be installed afterwards. It's weird that there is absolutely no documentation on the one I wound up with. The only documents I see all say, 'download `vsftpd`.'

Comment: Yeah pretty weird, weird that I have it.  Apart from an apache install the server is a fresh build :(  At least it's working!